# How to delete a specific piece of data from an XML file using VBA with access

Tags: xml, ms-access, import, vba

I am looking to delete a specific part of the xml file then import to a new table in access. Everything works but there is a node in the xml that is stopping this being imported.

I am looking to delete the node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<spark>
    <__status>success</__status>
    <active>true</active>
    <activity_due/>
    <approval>Not Yet Requested</approval>
    <approval_history/>
    <approval_set/>
    <assigned_to>Andrew Mansell</assigned_to>
    <assignment_group>Reference Data Support</assignment_group>
    <business_duration/>
    <calendar_duration/>
    <calendar_stc/>
    <close_notes/>
    <closed_at/>
    <closed_by/>
    <cmdb_ci/>
    <comments/>
    <comments_and_work_notes/>
    <company/>
    <contact_type/>
    <correlation_display/>
    <correlation_id/>
    <delivery_plan/>
    <delivery_task/>
    <description>Variables:&#x0D;
&#x0D;
Products: - Not Applicable&#x0D;
Business Owner: - Craig Hartnett&#x0D;
Full Details/Special Instructions: - Please find attached work order&#x0D;
Reason Codes: - Not Applicable&#x0D;
Business Area: - TVPROD Retention &#x0D;
Priority: - Low&#x0D;
Retailers: - Not Applicable&#x0D;
Due by Date: - 14/10/2016 13:12:14&#x0D;
Correspondence: - Not Applicable&#x0D;
Rules: - Not Applicable&#x0D;
Title: - TVPROD29572 HD PACK TEST WEEK 16-17&#x0D;
Offers: - Not Applicable</description>
    <due_date/>
    <escalation>Normal</escalation>
    <expected_start/>
    <follow_up/>
    <group_list/>
    <impact/>
    <knowledge>false</knowledge>
    <location/>
    <made_sla>true</made_sla>
    <number>RQTASK1381986</number>
    <opened_at>2016-10-10 12:12:30</opened_at>
    <opened_by/>
    <order/>
    <parent>REQ0739816</parent>
    <priority/>
    <reassignment_count>0</reassignment_count>
    <request>REQ0739816</request>
    <request_item/>
    <sc_catalog/>
    <short_description>TVPROD29572 HD PACK TEST WEEK 16-17</short_description>
    <skills/>
    <sla_due/>
    <state>Work in Progress</state>
    <sys_class_name>Request Task</sys_class_name>
    <sys_created_by>system</sys_created_by>
    <sys_created_on>2016-10-10 12:12:30</sys_created_on>
    <sys_domain>global</sys_domain>
    <sys_id>64a86bfa375eea40eea40c5754990e80</sys_id>
    <sys_mod_count>1</sys_mod_count>
    <sys_tags/>
    <sys_updated_by>cal25</sys_updated_by>
    <sys_updated_on>2016-10-14 11:47:57</sys_updated_on>
    <time_worked/>
    <u_affected_ci_list/>
    <u_approval_group/>
    <u_ass_to_man>true</u_ass_to_man>
    <u_attachment_key/>
    <u_causal_ci_list/>
    <u_customer_satisfaction_comments/>
    <u_customer_satisfaction_result/>
    <u_dep_sys_mod>false</u_dep_sys_mod>
    <u_department/>
    <u_div_sys_mod>false</u_div_sys_mod>
    <u_division/>
    <u_enhancement/>
    <u_enters_on_hold_status/>
    <u_expected_delivery_time_durat>2016-10-15 12:12:30</u_expected_delivery_time_durat>
    <u_impacted_areas/>
    <u_last_work_note>Craig Allan : template done sent for andy to approval</u_last_work_note>
    <u_last_work_note_date_and_time>2016-10-14 11:47:57</u_last_work_note_date_and_time>
    <u_leaves_on___hold_status/>
    <u_nsr/>
    <u_on_hold_pending_time/>
    <u_outage_type>No Service Impact</u_outage_type>
    <u_owner/>
    <u_owner_group/>
    <u_related_release/>
    <u_req_type/>
    <u_requested_for>Kavita Nanda</u_requested_for>
    <u_requested_for_date>2016-10-14</u_requested_for_date>
    <u_ritm/>
    <u_scheduled_end_date/>
    <u_scheduled_end_duration/>
    <u_scheduled_start_date/>
    <u_start_time_duration/>
    <u_sub_status_/>
    <u_sys_ass>false</u_sys_ass>
    <u_task_priority/>
    <u_task_status>Work in Progress</u_task_status>
    <u_time_to_complete/>
    <u_updated>false</u_updated>
    <u_updated_by_user/>
    <u_user_unavailable/>
    <u_vendor>false</u_vendor>
    <upon_approval>Proceed to Next Task</upon_approval>
    <upon_reject>Cancel all future Tasks</upon_reject>
    <urgency/>
    <user_input/>
    <watch_list/>
    <work_end/>
    <work_notes/>
    <work_notes_list/>
    <work_start/>
</spark>
```

The part I need to delete is;

```
<description>Variables:&#x0D;
    &#x0D;
    Products: - Not Applicable&#x0D;
    Business Owner: - Craig Hartnett&#x0D;
    Full Details/Special Instructions: - Please find attached work order&#x0D;
    Reason Codes: - Not Applicable&#x0D;
    Business Area: - TVPROD Retention &#x0D;
    Priority: - Low&#x0D;
    Retailers: - Not Applicable&#x0D;
    Due by Date: - 14/10/2016 13:12:14&#x0D;
    Correspondence: - Not Applicable&#x0D;
    Rules: - Not Applicable&#x0D;
    Title: - TVPROD29572 HD PACK TEST WEEK 16-17&#x0D;
    Offers: - Not Applicable</description>
```

My VBA code so far is;

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()

Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60, myurl As String, MyOutput As String

myurl = "http://10.74.18.2:8000/service=46&ticket_number=RQTASK1381986&xml=true"
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.send

  MyOutput = Mid(xmlhttp.responseText, 5)


Open "C:/Users/los07/Documents/test.xml" For Output As #1
Print #1, MyOutput

Application.ImportXML "C:/Users/los07/Documents/test.xml", acStructureAndData


End Sub
```

how can I select and delete the specific part?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an XSL template file named "dropDescription.xslt"

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="description">
        <!-- omit this item -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then have your VBA code call `Application.TransformXML` to pre-process the XML before importing it:

```vbs
Application.TransformXML _
        "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\test.xml", _
        "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\dropDescription.xslt", _
        "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\transformed.xml"
Application.ImportXML "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\transformed.xml", acStructureAndData
```